# .Net speed vs Custom Code speed

Tags: c#, .net, array, speed

In an `int?[]` garunteed to have original values, I wanted to find the index of null, which will only be a single index.

I drilled into the `Array.IndexOf(T[] array, T value)` .NET and, after all of the contracts and index checks, it comes down to this method:

```
internal virtual int IndexOf(T[] array, T value, int startIndex, int count){
    int endIndex = startIndex + count;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
        if (Equals(array[i], value)) return i;

    return -1;
}
```

I have three different instances which attempt a basic loop with `array[i] == null`, `Equals(array[i], null)`, and using `Array.IndexOf(null)`.  I realize ticks and stopwatch time is relative to what's happening on the machine at the time, and the machine in general.  But this is the code and benchmarks:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int?[] jankedArray;
        int missingElement = GenRandomizedArrayWithExtraEmptyElement(10000, out jankedArray);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        List<long> DotNetTicks = new List<long>();
        List<long> LikeDotNetTicks = new List<long>();
        List<long> BasicLoopTicks = new List<long>();
        IArrayAnalyzer arrayAnalyzer;
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            arrayAnalyzer = new AnalyzerLikeDotNet();
            sw.Restart(); arrayAnalyzer.GetMissingElement(jankedArray); sw.Stop();
            LikeDotNetTicks.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

            arrayAnalyzer = new AnalyzerBasic();
            sw.Restart(); arrayAnalyzer.GetMissingElement(jankedArray); sw.Stop();
            BasicLoopTicks.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);

            arrayAnalyzer = new AnalyzerUsingDotNet();
            sw.Restart(); arrayAnalyzer.GetMissingElement(jankedArray); sw.Stop();
            DotNetTicks.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("LikeDotNet / DotNet = " + LikeDotNetTicks.Average() / DotNetTicks.Average());
        Console.WriteLine("Basic / DotNet = " + BasicLoopTicks.Average() / DotNetTicks.Average());

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int GenRandomizedArrayWithExtraEmptyElement(int valueCount, out int?[] incompleteArray)
    {
        incompleteArray = new int?[valueCount + 1];
        Random random = new Random();

        int randomMissingIndex = random.Next(0, valueCount);

        var valueArray = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= valueCount; i++) valueArray.Add(i);

        var arrayElementAt = 0;
        while (valueArray.Count > 0)
        {
            if (arrayElementAt != randomMissingIndex)
            {
                var randomElement = random.Next(0, valueArray.Count);
                var valueAtRandom = valueArray.ElementAt(randomElement);
                valueArray.RemoveAt(randomElement);
                incompleteArray[arrayElementAt] = valueAtRandom;
            }
            arrayElementAt++;
        }

        return randomMissingIndex;
    }
}

public interface IArrayAnalyzer
{
    int GetMissingElement(int?[] incompleteArray);
}

public class AnalyzerUsingDotNet : IArrayAnalyzer
{
    public int GetMissingElement(int?[] incompleteArray)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(incompleteArray, null);
    }
}

public class AnalyzerLikeDotNet : IArrayAnalyzer
{
    public int GetMissingElement(int?[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            if (Equals(array[i], null)) return i;

        return -1;
    }
}

public class AnalyzerBasic : IArrayAnalyzer
{
    public int GetMissingElement(int?[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            if (array[i] == null) return i;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

- Output:
- LikeDotNet / DotNet = 81.3577324867023
- Basic / DotNet = 3.29459064916075

What am I missing between AnalyzerLikeDotNet and AnalyzerUsingDotNet which makes the execution time so different?

Comment: You have: an array of: optional int.  

System.Array is supporting something slightly different: an array of: int, which is a rather efficient data structure. 

C# stores optional int as Nullable<T>, which is a struct, so I don't think this will even get boxed.  It is a larger data structure (as much as 2x) but not terrible enough to merit 10x.  

Having debugging turned on can result in slower code.  

Also, timing C# code can have issues, because you may be timing the JIT plus the run instead of the just the run of the JIT'ed code.

Comment: These are all things I realize, except: System.Array is working with my Nullable<T> int?[].  So I'm not sure what you are implying when you say System.Array supports int[].  System.Array supports all T, and in both snippets above, the type is Nullable<int>.  It almost sounds like you're saying System.Array is treating it as int[], but then how is the Equals(T, T) taking an T[] array and comparing it to a null value?  I'm missing something in the direction you're going.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misspoke.  All I'm really saying is that Nullable<T> costs some but I don't see how that accounts for 10x.  So, maybe try to rule out some other things like timing methodology.

Comment: Why are you using a boxing `Equals` function, instead of `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`? Or just `array[i] == null` since your code isn't even generic.

Comment: My original code was `array[i] == null`, but when it was slower than `IndexOf()`, I tried matching what `IndexOf()` was doing.  Hunting down the mystery.  I am about to post my measuring code.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. `Array.IndexOf` does not boil down to the code you posted, it has a special  case for `null` and also a special native handler for basic primitive types. Even so, using your code (but with more reasonable benchmarking) I only get about a 1.5x slow down on the custom loop with optimization enabled.

Comment: Rotem, I'm not sure that's true.  I only see null handling on the `Array`, not on the `Value`.  I also get a 1.5x slowdown when I compare `Array.IndexOf() `with a basic loop using `array[i] == null`, but when I use the same `Equals` as the .net version, it's actually been avraging more like 50x slower.

Comment: @Suamere I'm looking at the source code, I definitely see special handing of `null`: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Array@cs/2/Array@cs

Comment: @Rotem That seems broken.  Try this: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,9dfd2c89c8d18414 - Still, the code looks the same.  And it is checking for null on the array, but not special handling null for the value.

Comment: @Suamere Oh scratch that, I was looking at the non-generic code.

Comment: @Rotem Right.  Good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my machine, the result of the benchmark (compiled in optimized Release mode) is

```
 LikeDotNet / DotNet = 101.911379048464

 Basic / DotNet = 0.979227574248443
```

so the second is near to ratio of 1, which is a strong indication the internal implementation in the framework is very similar to your `Basic` case. The 2% difference are most probably just from the overhead of the additional method call, or from additional checks inside the framework.

Having a look at the [link to the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,9dfd2c89c8d18414) code you posted it seems `Array.IndexOf` delegates it's calls to

```
  EqualityComparer<T>.Default.IndexOf
```

(line 1406), and the `Default` comparer is initialized by a [`CreateComparer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs,542680fa5b2d828d) method which picks one of several special `EqualityComparer<T>` derivations, optimized for some standard types. For `int?` this means the `IndexOf` method of `NullableEqualityComparer<T>` will be used, which uses `.HasValue` for `null` testing, not `Equals`. A quick benchmark with

```
    public int GetMissingElement(int?[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            if (!array[i].HasValue) return i;
        return -1;
    }
```

shows similar performance like your `Basic` test using `==` (or similar to calling `Array.IndexOf` directly). So I think this is what is really happening here - `.HasValue` has probably a much better performance (>factor 100) than `Equals` for `int?`.

Comment: Your answer does more of what I want, to break down the code and find where the difference is.  The answer being in the utilization of HasValue over Equals, as well as directing to NullableEqualityComparer.  Though John Wu's answer is the short and sweet fact.  But it makes more sense with all the snippets and description.  Good find!

Answer (score 3):

> Value types do not provide an overload for == by default.
>   However, most of the value types provided by the framework provide their
>   own overload. The default implementation of Equals for a value
>   type is provided by ValueType, and uses reflection
>   to make the comparison, **which makes it significantly slower than a
>   type-specific implementation normally would be.** This implementation also
>   calls Equals on pairs of references within the two values
>   being compared.

[Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals/)